# Zuul Locked Doors

Tags: java

Ex. 6.44: Add locked exits to your game. The player needs to find (or otherwise obtain) a key to unlock the exit and enter a room. (You don't need to add a new class for doors or exits to your game). Make this as general as possible - in any room, any exit could potentially be locked.

I have no idea how to do this. One idea was to make a HashMap with direction as keys and boolean (true/false) as values. Any suggestions?

```
*  This class is the main class of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 *  "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  Users 
 *  can walk around some scenery. That's all. It should really be extended 
 *  to make it more interesting!
 * 
 *  To play this game, create an instance of this class and call the "play"
 *  method.
 * 
 *  This main class creates and initialises all the others: it creates all
 *  rooms, creates the parser and starts the game.  It also evaluates and
 *  executes the commands that the parser returns.
 * 
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */

public class Game 
{
    private Parser parser;
    private Room currentRoom;
    private Room roomStack[];
    private int top;
    private Player player;
    private Character character;
    /**
     * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
     */
    public Game() 
    {
        createRooms();
        parser = new Parser();
        roomStack = new Room[500];
        top = -1;
    }

    /**
     * Adds character object.
     */
    public void addCharacter(Character character)
    {
        this.character = character;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the character object.
     */
    public Character getCharacter()
    {
        return character;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the items possessed by a player
     */
    public void printItem()
    {
        System.out.println(player.getItems());
    }

    /**
     * Create all the rooms and link their exits together.
     */
    private void createRooms()
    {
        Room outside, theater, pub, lab, office, basement, dungeon;

        // create the rooms
        outside = new Room("outside the main entrance of the university");
        theater = new Room("in a lecture theater");
        pub = new Room("in the campus pub");
        lab = new Room("in a computing lab");
        office = new Room("in the computing admin office");
        basement = new Room("in the basement, where the key is!");
        dungeon = new Room("in the dungeon");

        // initialise room exits
        outside.setExit("east", theater);
        outside.setExit("south", lab);
        outside.setExit("west", pub);

        theater.setExit("west", outside);

        pub.setExit("east", outside);

        lab.setExit("north", outside);
        lab.setExit("east", office);

        office.setExit("west", lab);

        basement.setExit("north", office);
        basement.addItems("key", "key to unlock door", 1);

        currentRoom = outside;  // start game outside
    }

    /**
     *  Main play routine.  Loops until end of play.
     */
    public void play() 
    {            
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = reader.nextLine();
        player = new Player(name);
        printWelcome();

        // Enter the main command loop.  Here we repeatedly read commands and
        // execute them until the game is over.

        boolean finished = false;
        while (! finished) {
            Command command = parser.getCommand();
            finished = processCommand(command);
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you " + player.getName() + " for playing.  Good bye.");
    }

    /**
     * Print out the opening message for the player.
     */
    private void printWelcome()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Hello " + player.getName() + ",");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the World of Zuul!");
        System.out.println("World of Zuul is a new, incredibly boring adventure game.");
        System.out.println("Type 'help' if you need help.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
    }

    /**
     * Given a command, process (that is: execute) the command.
     * @param command The command to be processed.
     * @return true If the command ends the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean processCommand(Command command) 
    {
        boolean wantToQuit = false;

        if(command.isUnknown()) {
            System.out.println("I don't know what you mean...");
            return false;
        }

        String commandWord = command.getCommandWord();
        if (commandWord.equals("help")) {
            printHelp();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("go")) {
            goRoom(command);
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("quit")) {
            wantToQuit = quit(command);
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("back")) {
            backRoom();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("eat")) {
            System.out.println("You have eaten now and are not hungry anymore.");
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("take")) {
            player.pickUpItem();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("drop")) {
            player.dropItem();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("items")) {
            printItem();
        }
        else if (commandWord.equals("eatcookie")) {
            player.eatCookie();
        }
        // else command not recognised.
        return wantToQuit;
    }

    // implementations of user commands:

    /**
     * Print out some help information.
     * Here we print some stupid, cryptic message and a list of the 
     * command words.
     */
    private void printHelp() 
    {
        System.out.println("You are lost. You are alone. You wander");
        System.out.println("around at the university.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your command words are:");
        parser.showCommands();
    }

    /** 
     * Try to in to one direction. If there is an exit, enter the new
     * room, otherwise print an error message.
     */
    private void goRoom(Command command) 
    {
        if(!command.hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
            System.out.println("Go where?");
            return;
        }

        String direction = command.getSecondWord();

        // Try to leave current room.
        Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExit(direction);

        if (nextRoom == null) {
            System.out.println("There is no door!");
        }
        else {
            push(currentRoom);
            currentRoom = nextRoom;
            if(character != null && !person.hasSpoken())
            {
                System.out.println("There is a person in this room");
                System.out.println(character.getName() + ": " + character.getDialogue());
                person.setHasSpoken(true);
            }
            System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to go to the previous room, and display that
     * room's information.
     */
    private void backRoom()
    {
        currentRoom = pop();
        if(currentRoom != null)
        {
            System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the current room to the stack.
     * @param room The room to add to the stack.
     */
    private void push(Room room)
    {
        if(top == roomStack.length-1)
        {
            System.out.println("Room stack is full.");
        }
        else
        {
            roomStack[++top] = room;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the room at the top of the roomStack.
     * @return Room if it exists and null otherwise.
     */
    private Room pop()
    {
        if(top<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you are outside, and there is no previous room to which you can go back.");
            return null;                    
        }
        else
        {
            return roomStack[top--];
        }
    }

    /** 
     * "Quit" was entered. Check the rest of the command to see
     * whether we really quit the game.
     * @return true, if this command quits the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean quit(Command command) 
    {
        if(command.hasSecondWord()) {
            System.out.println("Quit what?");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;  // signal that we want to quit
        }
    }
}
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Class Room - a room in an adventure game.
 *
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 *
 * A "Room" represents one location in the scenery of the game.  It is 
 * connected to other rooms via exits.  For each existing exit, the room 
 * stores a reference to the neighboring room.
 * 
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */

public class Room 
{
    private String description;
    private HashMap<String, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
    private HashMap items;
    /**
     * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
     * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
     * "an open court yard".
     * @param description The room's description.
     */
    public Room(String description) 
    {
        this.description = description;
        exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
        items = new HashMap();
    }

    /**
     * Define an exit from this room.
     * @param direction The direction of the exit.
     * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
     */
    public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor) 
    {
        exits.put(direction, neighbor);
    }
// 
//      /**
//      * This sets the doors of rooms as locked or not.
//      */
//     public void setRoomDoors(String direction, Room room, boolean locked)
//     {
//         exits.put(direction, room, locked);
//     }

    /**
     * @return The short description of the room
     * (the one that was defined in the constructor).
     */
    public String getShortDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Return a description of the room in the form:
     *     You are in the kitchen.
     *     Exits: north west
     * @return A long description of this room
     */
    public String getLongDescription()
    {
        return "You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the room's exits, for example
     * "Exits: north west".
     * @return Details of the room's exits.
     */
    private String getExitString()
    {
        String returnString = "Exits:";
        Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit : keys) {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    /**
     * Return the room that is reached if we go from this room in direction
     * "direction". If there is no room in that direction, return null.
     * @param direction The exit's direction.
     * @return The room in the given direction.
     */
    public Room getExit(String direction) 
    {
        return exits.get(direction);
    }

    /**
     * This method adds items to a room.
     */
    public void addItems(String item_name, String description, int weight)
    {
        items.put(item_name, new Item(description, weight));
    }
}

/**
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 *
 * This class holds information about a command that was issued by the user.
 * A command currently consists of two strings: a command word and a second
 * word (for example, if the command was "take map", then the two strings
 * obviously are "take" and "map").
 * 
 * The way this is used is: Commands are already checked for being valid
 * command words. If the user entered an invalid command (a word that is not
 * known) then the command word is <null>.
 *
 * If the command had only one word, then the second word is <null>.
 * 
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */

public class Command
{
    private String commandWord;
    private String secondWord;

    /**
     * Create a command object. First and second word must be supplied, but
     * either one (or both) can be null.
     * @param firstWord The first word of the command. Null if the command
     *                  was not recognised.
     * @param secondWord The second word of the command.
     */
    public Command(String firstWord, String secondWord)
    {
        commandWord = firstWord;
        this.secondWord = secondWord;
    }

    /**
     * Return the command word (the first word) of this command. If the
     * command was not understood, the result is null.
     * @return The command word.
     */
    public String getCommandWord()
    {
        return commandWord;
    }

    /**
     * @return The second word of this command. Returns null if there was no
     * second word.
     */
    public String getSecondWord()
    {
        return secondWord;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if this command was not understood.
     */
    public boolean isUnknown()
    {
        return (commandWord == null);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the command has a second word.
     */
    public boolean hasSecondWord()
    {
        return (secondWord != null);
    }
}

/**
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.
 * 
 * This class holds an enumeration of all command words known to the game.
 * It is used to recognise commands as they are typed in.
 *
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */

public class CommandWords
{
    // a constant array that holds all valid command words
    private static final String[] validCommands = {
        "go", "quit", "help", "back", "eat", "take", "drop", "items", "eatcookie"
    };

    /**
     * Constructor - initialise the command words.
     */
    public CommandWords()
    {
        // nothing to do at the moment...
    }

    /**
     * Check whether a given String is a valid command word. 
     * @return true if it is, false if it isn't.
     */
    public boolean isCommand(String aString)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < validCommands.length; i++) {
            if(validCommands[i].equals(aString))
                return true;
        }
        // if we get here, the string was not found in the commands
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Print all valid commands to System.out.
     */
    public void showAll() 
    {
        for(String command: validCommands) {
            System.out.print(command + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 * 
 * This parser reads user input and tries to interpret it as an "Adventure"
 * command. Every time it is called it reads a line from the terminal and
 * tries to interpret the line as a two word command. It returns the command
 * as an object of class Command.
 *
 * The parser has a set of known command words. It checks user input against
 * the known commands, and if the input is not one of the known commands, it
 * returns a command object that is marked as an unknown command.
 * 
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.08.08
 */
public class Parser 
{
    private CommandWords commands;  // holds all valid command words
    private Scanner reader;         // source of command input

    /**
     * Create a parser to read from the terminal window.
     */
    public Parser() 
    {
        commands = new CommandWords();
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * @return The next command from the user.
     */
    public Command getCommand() 
    {
        String inputLine;   // will hold the full input line
        String word1 = null;
        String word2 = null;

        System.out.print("> ");     // print prompt

        inputLine = reader.nextLine();

        // Find up to two words on the line.
        Scanner tokenizer = new Scanner(inputLine);
        if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
            word1 = tokenizer.next();      // get first word
            if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
                word2 = tokenizer.next();      // get second word
                // note: we just ignore the rest of the input line.
            }
        }

        // Now check whether this word is known. If so, create a command
        // with it. If not, create a "null" command (for unknown command).
        if(commands.isCommand(word1)) {
            return new Command(word1, word2);
        }
        else {
            return new Command(null, word2); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print out a list of valid command words.
     */
    public void showCommands()
    {
        commands.showAll();
    }
}
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class Item here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Item
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int weight;
    private String magicCookie;
    private HashMap items;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(String description, int weight)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.description = description;
       this.weight = weight;
       items = new HashMap();
       this.magicCookie = "Cookies";
    }

    /**
     * This returns the description of an item.
     * @return description
     */
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * This returns the weight of an item.
     * @return weight
     */
    public int getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    /**
     * This adds items to the items HashMap.
     */
    private void addItems()
    {
        items.put("bottle", new Item("A water bottle", 1));
        items.put("camera", new Item("digital camera", 2));
        items.put("clock", new Item("wall clock", 1));
        items.put("sponge", new Item("bath sponge", 1));
        items.put("key", new Item("key to unlock door", 1));
    }

    /**
     * Return a description of the items contained in a room.
     * @return a description of the item with weight.
     */
    public String getItemDescription()
    {
        String itemString = "This room contains :";
        itemString = itemString + this.name + "\n";
        itemString = itemString + "Description: " + this.description + "\n";
        itemString = itemString + "Weight: " + this.weight + "\n";
        itemString = itemString + "\nThis room has cookies";
        return itemString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question so I am a little weary of answering it. I'll give you my general thoughts, feel free to update your question with any code you come up with and we can help you further.

---

Based on the task description, the first instinct is that this "locked/unlocked" functionality belongs to the Room itself so I would suggest adding an indicator to the `Room` class that would indicate the current state of that room's exit(s). This is similar to your idea of having a HashMap of all the exits with their "locked" status. The Room should also know what key specifically would unlock each of its doors.

Next, you would need to add some logic that prevents the user from walking through a locked door. Take a look at the `goRoom()` method. You can incorporate your "locked" logic there. Check if a player has some keys and then try to iterate through them and try to unlock the exit in the `Room` class.